# Serilog with a custom template and JSON formatter

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm using Serilog with ASP.NET Core 2.1, and configure it via the `appsettings.json`.

The default template doesn't include `{SourceContext}`, so I use my own template which includes it. But I also want structured logging with JSON.

I read somewhere in the Serilog wiki that I can't specify `formatter` (for JSON output) and `outputTemplate` at the same time.

So I can't do this for example:

```
"outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd} {Level:u3} {SourceContext} {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
"formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact"
```

So how can I get JSON output, but also get the `SourceContext` data that I need?

Comment: Hello @Ionix : I have almost the same problem and In can't find anywhere how to use a formatter and a custom template at the same time. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @kbaccouche Sorry my friend that was for an old project and I can't remember :-( I recall there was something relevant on the github repo... you might want to check there. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure what's changed since the question was asked, but now I do get the `SourceContext` variable. I'm using `Serilog.AspNetCore` version `3.4.0`, on ASP.NET Core 5.

This works:

```json
{
  "Name": "File",
  "Args": {
    // ...
    //"outputTemplate": "",                          // DO NOT USE THIS
    "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact"
  }
}
```

Just don't use `outputTemplate` and `formatter` at the same time.

This config gives me variables `@t`, `@mt`, `@l`, `SourceContext`.

Note `@l` is not included for `Information` level as that's considered the default.